# Interface 'Silex\ControllerProviderInterface' not found in Controller

Tags: php, silex

When executing api.php:

> Fatal error: Interface 'Silex\ControllerProviderInterface' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\lab\src\Api\UserController.php on line 9

Composer:

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Api\\": "src/Api"
        }
    }
}
```

api.php :

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new Silex\Application();

$app['debug'] = true;

$app->mount('/', new Api\UserController());

$app->run();
```

src/Api/UserController.php :

```
<?php
namespace Api;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Silex\Application;
use Silex\ControllerProviderInterface;

class UserController implements ControllerProviderInterface {

  public function connect(Application $app) {
    $factory=$app['controllers_factory'];
    $factory->get('/','Api\UserController::home');
    return $factory;
  }

  public function home() {
    return 'Hello world';
  }

}
```

How files are organized :

```
root folder
- composer.json
- api.php
-  src 
        - Api
              - UserController.php
- vendor (with silex files)
```

Silex was installed by composer `composer require silex/silex *` at root folder.

Answer (score 7):

Silex 2.0 introduced a few BC breacks. One of these was the creation of the [Silex\Api namespace where the ControllerProviderInterface resides now](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Api/ControllerProviderInterface.php#L12).

So you have to refactor your UserController:

```
<?php
namespace Api;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Silex\Application;
use Silex\Api\ControllerProviderInterface;
//       ^^^^^

class UserController implements ControllerProviderInterface {
// ...
```